# How to play embedded resource sound in given time interval? Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, audio, timer

I am trying to make small application (to troll friends) that should play an embedded resource sound file (embedded in `Resources.resx`). I am using the method of the namespace `System.Media.SoundPlayer`. When tried to execute the sound play code directly in the `MainWin` workspace, it works, but plays only once. So I decided to place it in timer with following code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWin : Form
    {
        public MainWin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Interval = 120000;
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        /// some other code that has nothing to do with sound

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new System.Media.SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.resName).Play();
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not work, the application is silent, no sound is playing on the background. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Have you `Start`ed the timer?

Comment: You mean method `Start()`? No, totally forgot :D Thank you :D Anyway I figured out the better is to play sound when clicked a button (which also displays a message box). But thank you, it's useful to the future times when I will really need to play sound in given interval :)